# Как в списке преобразовать все строки, содержащие в себе числа в int (без циклов)?

Tags: python, строки, числа, преобразование-типов

Допустим, мы имеем такой список, в котором числа могут стоять в любом порядке:

```
a = [["Саша", "15", "Яблоко"], ["7", "Игорь"], ["Елена", "71", "984", "Слива"]]
```

Как не используя циклы преобразовать все числа в тип данных int? Может есть какая - нибудь библиотека для этого?

Comment: а как дальше эти цифры будут использоваться ? может там в инт а не в списке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
a = [["Саша", "15", "Яблоко"], ["7", "Игорь"], ["Елена", "71", "984", "Слива"]]


def try_to_int(val):
    if isinstance(val, list):
        return [*map(try_to_int, val)]
    try:
        return int(val)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return val


print(try_to_int(a))
# [['Саша', 15, 'Яблоко'], [7, 'Игорь'], ['Елена', 71, 984, 'Слива']]
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Особенно полезно было узнать про конструкцию try - except